# Acquiring all values of nested dictionaries that contain the same key using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'm still trying to get a handle on LINQ, and while I do have a bit of an understanding for the simpler functions, stacking these eludes me to a certain extent, I'm hoping someone can lend me a hand.

I currently have a dictionary that is effectively:

```
Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<int, EntityComponent>> ComponentSystems
```

I'm trying to write a method that will return all instances of EntityComponent that have a given key, that is, if the parent dictionary contains two nested dictionaries and each of them have an entry with '1' as the key, the method will return the values that match said key as an `IEnumerable<EntityComponent>`

I've muched around with `SelectMany` and all the various other LINQ commands but I'm still struggling to figure it out.

As another example just to be clear, lets say I have the following setup:

```
Dictionary<object, Dictionary<int, string>> test = 
   new Dictionary<object, Dictionary<int, string>>();

Dictionary<int, string> test1 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
test1[1] = "test1-1";
test1[2] = "test1-2";
test[0] = test1;

Dictionary<int, string> test2 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
test2[1] = "test2-1";
test2[2] = "test2-2";
test[1] = test2;
```

Given that the key I'm looking for is '1', I would need to produce a linq statement that would return both "test1-1" and "test2-1".

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking for `GroupBy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int key = 1;
var query = test.Values // select inner dictionaries
                .Where(d => d.ContainsKey(key)) // which contain your key
                .Select(d => d[key]); // and return value by key
```

Returns:

```
"test1-1"
"test2-1"
```

Comment: I was over-complicating things it would seem, thank you for your help.